# SQL query by supplier

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, looking for a query to "flag products for 'delete', by costkind, where PLU is identified."

**Example**

```
UPDATE PROD 
SET ChangeFlag = 'D'
WHERE costkind IN ('xxxx', 'xxxx')
WHERE plu IN ('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

I can't quite get the query correct,

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Replace the second `WHERE` with an `AND` ..... which you'd easily see if you'd consulted the [official Microsoft docs on `SELECT` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ....

Comment: **Typo** alert - it's a **query** - not a "quiery" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple conditions for your `WHERE` clause, you need to combine them with `OR` or `AND` - not repeat `WHERE`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE PROD 
SET ChangeFlag = 'D'
WHERE costkind IN ('xxxx', 'xxxx')
  AND plu IN ('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

Comment: Also misspelt your name, sorry mate! that update seems to do the trick, much appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely will do, thankyou again